# dojo comboBox automatically trigger dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox, triggers, dojo

I am using a `comboBox` and for some reason the automaticall triger for the dropdown menu to appear when you have some results is not working. Is there any way to trigger this dynamically. Maybe `onChange` event?

I am using dojo 1.6!

Comment: Can you post some code or a jsfiddle perhaps to better show the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A code example would be nice so as we can recommend alternatives or better solutions, but in the case that all you want to do is open a dropdown programmatically, you should find openDropDown() and toggleDropDown() functions on the combobox object. If you have the dojo source you can find more dropdown related functions in dijit/_HasDropDown.js, which combo box inherits from.